# SQL Server - Split amount on rows with period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert invoice data amount to actual cost per month. Any suggestion?

I have a table like this:

```
InvoiceID   INVOICE_DATE               AMOUNT   SplitOnNumberOfMonthToCome
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
23          2019-12-05 00:00:00.000    3000         3
24          2019-12-07 00:00:00.000    2000         1
25          2020-03-12 00:00:00.000    12000        3
26          2020-03-03 00:00:00.000    5000         1
```

And want this:

```
InvoiceID   MonthPeriod    Amount
---------------------------------------
23          202001         1000
23          202002         1000
23          202003         1000
24          202001         2000
25          202004         4000
25          202005         4000
25          202006         4000
26          202004         5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE.  If I understand correctly:

```
with cte as (
      select invoiceid, invoice_date, amount / num_months as month_amount, 1 as n, num_months
      from t
      union all
      select invoiceid, invoice_date, month_amount, n + 1, num_months
      from cte
      where n < num_months
     )
select inoiceid,
       format(dateadd(month, n, invoice_date), 'yyyymm') as monthperiod,
       month_amount
from cte;
```

Comment: @alexherm . . . I don't think so.  The OP is asking about breaking individual rows into multiple rows.

Comment: @Gordon  You're right, that was exactly what I was looking for. Solved my case!